# How can I programmatically switch between sound and a muted mode?

Tags: c#, audio, beep

I made beeps using

```
[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL")]
extern public static void Beep(int freq, int dur);

//  and

Beep(2222, 55);
Beep(3333, 55);
```

I have planted this code ( Beep( freq, dura) ) almost a hundread times here and there(with various frequency, duration and times).

Now, I want to switch between Sound and Mute programtically.

I could do it with something like

```
if ( my_Flag )
{
    Beep( 2222, 55);
    Beep( 3333, 55);
}
```

It should be tedious work to do.
Is there any better ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have used 'magic numbers' as you show in your example you need to do the 'tedious work'. While at it, better define some GLOBAL variable that you can change programmatically in your code and use them to replace the 'magic numbers'

Comment: I doubt there is a way to avoid what you mean by tedious work as there is no overload of the `Beep`-method that excepts a boolean indicating if it should produce a beep or not, so you have to check this yourself.

Comment: If I were you, I'd create a own (singleton class +) function(int,int) which will call Beep of Kernel32 itself... Then you'll have much less problems with something like this. Never the less, you won't have another way then refactor this I guess...

Comment: Ooooopsss. Thanks.... Steve, HimBromBeere and TripleEEE. I guess I made a big pain in the ass.

Comment: I suggest you edit the title to actually be a question. "Code improvement with easy" is not a question, and could mean pretty much anything.

Comment: @PetterHesselberg Any suggestion will be welcomed !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If everything is defined as `Beep(x,y)` method, You can write Your own method and then Refactor->Rename all methods to `MyBeep(x,y)` for example.

```
public void MyBeep(int freq, int dur)
{
    if(myFlag)
        Beep(freq, dur);
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm Sounds good to me. Though looks space shuttle tech to me. OK I will try it out. I am a beginner, You can know it easily with my question. Your answer is precious to me. thanks. Tatranskymedved

Comment: Not a problem. =)

Comment: Works perfectly !! Thanks again.